# Questions about isotypic subspaces and co-isotypic subspaces of $V$.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\chi: G \to \mathbb{C}^*$ a character. Let $(\pi,V)$ be a representation of $G$. The $(G, \chi)$-isotypic subspace of $V$ is defined by $$ V^{\chi}=\{v \in V: \pi(g)v=\chi(g)v, \forall g \in G\}. $$ The $(G, \chi)$-co-isotypic subspace of $V$ is defined by $$ V_{\chi} = V/V(\chi), V(\chi)=\operatorname{Span}_{\mathbb{C}}\{\pi(g)v-\chi(g)v, v \in V, g \in G\}. $$

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$ be the additive group. Let $V = \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{Z}] = \{\sum_{n}a_n [n]: a_n \in \mathbb{C}\}$. Define $\pi: \mathbb{Z} \to GL(V)$ by 
$$
\pi(s)\left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n [n] \right) = \sum_{n} a_n[n+s] = \sum_{n} a_{n-s}[n].
$$
Then $\pi$ is a representation of $\mathbb{Z}$. It is said that

(1) $V^{\chi}=0$ for all $\chi \in Hom(Z, \mathbb{C}^*)$ and

(2) $V_{\chi}$ is one-dimensional for all characters $\chi$.

I want to verify (1) and (2). Let $\sum_{n}a_n [n] \in V^{\chi}$. Then 
$$
\pi(s)\left( \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} a_n [n] \right) = \sum_{n} a_n[n+s] = \sum_{n} a_{n-s}[n]=\chi(s)\sum_{n}a_n [n], \forall s \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Therefore for each $s$ and $n$, $a_{n-s}=\chi(s)a_n$. But how could we conclude that $a_n = 0$ for all $n$? How to prove (2)? Thank you very much.

Comment: @JackSchmidt, yes, it is a typo. I will fix it. Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) is not true for a trivial character (take $a_n=1$)

Comment: @user68061: I suspect the elements of $V$ must have all but finitely many of the $a_n=0$ (the $\sigma$ and $[\mathbb{Z}]$ notations are often used that way, but they are also used other ways).

Comment: Assuming that is the case, choose $s$ larger than $|i-j|$ for any $i,j$ with $a_i  \neq 0 \neq a_j$.